# StreamWriter not working c#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

im using a lot of streamwrtier in my application, and this one is suppsoed to log errors that happens while the program is running but at the moment it only creates the file withour writing into it :

```
  if(File.Exists(currentLog))//currentLog = "Path\\Log.txt"
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.Open(currentLog,FileMode.Open))
            {
                StreamWriter ErreurStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
                ErreurStreamWriter.WriteLine("{0}",e.Message);
                ErreurStreamWriter.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(currentLog))
            {
                StreamWriter ErreurStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
                ErreurStreamWriter.Write("Liste des erreurs :");
                ErreurStreamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
                ErreurStreamWriter.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            }
        }
```

Am I missing something obvious here ? Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: `FileMode.Append` ? Also, I suggest forgetting the FileStream and directly using the StreamWriter by passing in the log file path as the only argument

Comment: You never close/flush the streamwriter

Comment: @CodeInChaos 
Using() block does that closing part indirectly via calling IDispose call.

Comment: @zenwalker the `FileStream` gets closed by the `using` statement, but the `StreamWriter` doesn't.

Comment: At first i was thinking like zenwlaker, i thought that the using statement closed the streamwriter too, it appears that it doesnt ^_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be need to Flush() after write, or try to append when exist

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(currentLog, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (StreamWriter erreurStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            { 
                erreurStreamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
                erreurStreamWriter.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            }
        }
```

Basically what I think happens is that the stream writer never flush into the filestream.